# Proof about indices of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to prove this thing about indices of subsequences: $n_k\geq k$. Is this proof acceptable?
Proof:
$n_0\in\mathbb N \Rightarrow n_0\geq 0$. Assume $n_k\geq k$ holds.
Then $n_{k+1}\overset{def.}{\geq} n_k +1\overset{ass.}{\geq} k+1$. Thus $n_{k+1}\geq k+1$. $n_k\geq k$ holds by Mathematical induction.

Comment: It's fine, although you could clarify a few parts with some more quantifiers.